# Display IP Address on Character Based LCD

Tags: python, rpi.gpio, dhcp

I need to know the IP address of my raspberry pi. I need to do this with a Character LCD display. So here's what I have done so far.

I can display text on a HD44780 based 16x2 LCD connected to my Raspberry-Pi as shown [here](http://www.raspberrypi-spy.co.uk/2012/07/16x2-lcd-module-control-using-python/).

Also using putty if i do `hostname -I` I get my local IP as 192.168.1.4

Now I think I need to *fire/execute* this command *'hostname -I'* using python, *grab* the result text( which will be the IP) string, and pass it to my lcd. MoreOver I need to do this once after every *DHCP address assignment*( I don't know the exact/correct name of this thing).
Now the problem is, my linux(raspian) knowledge is limited. I read on internet about CRON JOB but I'm unsure as to how to do this..

Kindly Help me out !!

Comment: Other than the printing to the LCD part of this question, this would probably fit better on [unix.se], as that is a broader, *nix-focused site, as opposed to this site, which is focused specifically on Raspberry Pi-specific issues.

Comment: @RPiAwesomeness I will raise a *migration* flag then. Thanks.

Comment: No problem! Please don't feel we don't want you and your questions here, it's just that RPi.SE is a very focused community, for issues that only occur on the Raspberry Pi (GPIO, RPi Cam, stuff that works on a normal system - but not on the RPi, etc.)

Comment: @RPiAwesomeness I see the rationale of pi-exchange more clearly now, its very focused on Pi related issue. Even as I am searching for *python command execute* and *linux dhcp* I am getting results from *stackoverflow* and *Unix and Linux*. So I've raised a migration flag. In the first place I came to this exchange.site thinking that someone might already have done such a thing. What better place then Pi-exchange site. I think I will get back with results to *here* again for *reference* purpose.

Answer (score 5):

cron job is easy, just type `crontab -e` and you'll get a chance to edit your cron job table, if you want your script to run every 10 minutes, you just add:

```
*/10 * * * * /home/pi/whatever.py
```

where `/home/pi/whatever.py` is your script that executes `hostname -I` and shows the result on your LCD panel.

Comment: (+1) It works! I reduced the time period further to 2 minutes. And I am still searching for the DHCP based solution/approach.

Answer (score 3):

here's explanation regarding DHCP part.

there are two directories in your system:

```
/etc/dhcp/dhclient-enter-hooks.d
/etc/dhcp/dhclient-exit-hooks.d
```

that contain scripts to be run when `dhcp` configuration changes. here's a sample script (most likely you have a similar one under the name `debug` in these directories):

```
#
# The purpose of this script is just to show the variables that are
# available to all the scripts in this directory. All these scripts
# are called from /etc/dhcp3/dhclient-script, which exports all the
# variables shown before. If you want to debug a problem with your DHCP
# setup you can enable this script and take a look at
# /tmp/dhclient-script.debug.

# To enable this script set the following variable to "yes"
RUN="no"

if [ "$RUN" = "yes" ]; then
    echo $(date): entering ${0%/*}, dumping variables. \
        >> /tmp/dhclient-script.debug

    # loop over the 4 possible prefixes: (empty), cur_, new_, old_
    for prefix in '' 'cur_' 'new_' 'old_'; do
        # loop over the DHCP variables passed to dhclient-script
        for basevar in reason interface medium alias_ip_address \
                   ip_address host_name network_number subnet_mask \
                   broadcast_address routers static_routes \
                   rfc3442_classless_static_routes \
                   domain_name domain_search domain_name_servers \
                   netbios_name_servers netbios_scope \
                   ntp_servers \
                   ip6_address ip6_prefix ip6_prefixlen \
                   dhcp6_domain_search dhcp6_name_servers ; do
            var="${prefix}${basevar}"

            # show only variables with values set
            if [ -n "${!var}" ]; then
                echo "$var='${!var}'" >> /tmp/dhclient-script.debug
            fi
        done
    done

    echo '--------------------------' >> /tmp/dhclient-script.debug
fi
```

you may copy this script under the name you like, enable it by setting `RUN="yes"` and have fun with the variables available (run it once to see the output in `/tmp/dhclient-script.debug`).

or maybe just ignore the variables and use `hostname -I` approach as before.

anyway, if you need a manual regarding these scripts, [check this](http://roy.marples.name/man/html8/dhcpcd-run-hooks.html).

Comment: AWESOME ! I think this is the ideal approach. A question for now. When I added the cron job( to execute my python script) in previous approach, I had to use the *sudo* prefix( **sudo python -u ip_disp_clcd.py**). However in this approach, as you told, I just need to copy my python script to the directory( supposedly *dhclient-exit-hooks.d*) and it will work. Won't it require the *sudo* force as the previous one did ??

Comment: @vvy why don't you try and see?

Comment: That's the first thing on my TODO list, I'll test it as soon as I receive my new R-Pi. I have submitted my previous R-Pi to the college [checkout this snap](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_OcX1Wr8s5WbEh2T0FMUXdqNUk/edit?usp=sharing).

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue. Even though you already have the answer for those looking for something that does the trick here's what I wrote using python and a PifaceCAD LCD

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
"""
Get's the local IPv4 address and displays to the user
Requires:
    * ifconfig
    * grep
    * awk
"""
import subprocess

import pifacecad

_VERSION = '0.1'

def get_ipv4():
    ip = subprocess.check_output('ifconfig | grep broadcast | awk \'{print $2}\'', shell=True).decode('utf-8')
    print('IP is: {}'.format(ip))
    return ip

def main(cad=None):
    if not cad:
        cad = pifacecad.PiFaceCad()
        cad.lcd.blink_off()
        cad.lcd.cursor_off()
    cad.lcd.clear()
    cad.lcd.home()
    cad.lcd.write('IPv4 Address:')
    ip = get_ipv4()
    cad.lcd.set_cursor(0, 1)
    cad.lcd.write(' ' * pifacecad.lcd.LCD_WIDTH)
    cad.lcd.set_cursor(0, 1)
    cad.lcd.write(ip)

    return 0

if __name__ == '__main__':
    sys.exit(main())
```

As you can see I didn't use the 'hostname -I' because I had limited success with that, for some reason even though it seems more complex the ifconfig/grep/awk solution worked better for me.