# How to write an IP change notifier script in Xbian?

Tags: ssh, script, sendemail

I am fed up with constant IP address changes which prevents me to reach my RPI via SSH. How can I write a script which sends me the current IP address when a change occurs?

Comment: Current IP address of what?

Comment: If you do not pay to your ISP for static IP, your IP address changes depending on the connection is dropped or due to something else. And if you go and check your IP address it is different each time. I just want to write a script probably will use ssmtp to send an e-mail whenever an IP address change occurs. But is there a way other than using cron to query the IP address periodically and if there's a change, make rpi send and e-mail using ssmtp?

Comment: Yes, the Pi could probably do that.  Any reason you don't use a free dynamic DNS service such as http://www.noip.com/free/ ?

Comment: I just checked it, anyways it does not seem so secure. I'll insist on writing my own script to make it.

Comment: you should check this: http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/15913/7274

Comment: @lenik I think that addresses finding the Pi's local IP address.  The OP wants the router's public address.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remember that this question is not specific to the Raspberry Pi. You could find answers on all sorts of general Linux sites.

The following bash script should find your router's IP address.

```
#!/bin/bash

NOWIP=$(curl ipecho.net/plain 2>/dev/null)
OLDIP=$(cat /tmp/myoldip 2>/dev/null)

if [[ "$NOWIP" = "$OLDIP" ]]; then
   echo "IP address is still $NOWIP"
else
   echo "old was $OLDIP, new is $NOWIP"
   echo $NOWIP >/tmp/myoldip
   # send e-mail here
fi
```

Put the text in a file called getip and make it executable with chmod +x getip.

The method of sending e-mail will depend on what mail packages you have installed and any mail servers to which you have access.

Comment: Great script! +1

Answer (score 2):

You should use a dynamic dns client as you can get loads of free domains. The Pi pushes its IP to the DNS Domain every so often and all you have to remember is `mydomain.free-dns.com`

[Here is a tutorial](http://blog.mivia.dk/free-dynamic-dns-for-raspberry-pi/)

```
sudo apt-get install ddclient
```

edit the configuration file

```
/etc/ddclient.conf
```

You can use `ddclient` on most free dynamic dns's. I like to use no-ip.

In [my book](http://www.packtpub.com/raspberry-pi-server-essentials/book) I explain how to push dynamic IP's to a real domain, like `pi.my.house` - I use this technique for loads of people and all i have to remember is. `friend.my.house` or `nan.my.solutions` or `server.ppumkin.me`

Comment: I've been using this approach for years, works like a charm! =)